# JTwain API not responding from applet

Tags: twain

We had been migrating our projects to Linux from windows.Among which is a Java Applet being invoked from a JSP to facilitate scanning via JTwain API.This has stopped working.On checking the Applet console , code execution seems to be smooth till the following

`com.asprise.util.jtwain.Source source.acquireImage()`

There is no exception being thrown as well. Also , jar signing has also been done (Though there is another application that works superbly even without this).

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

This is my first question on the forum , kindly excuse if there had been any non-compliance with standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot the issue, you may test with the [JTwain web demo](http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/applet/index.php) on your Windows machine to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the response Rachel ! The scanning works smoothly through another application from the same machine.The only change we have done is migration of the server side from windows to linux. I still cant think of reasons why the applet would fail due to this.Moreover there is another applet which works smoothly from the same client PC.

Comment: Well I know this is really stupid , lately we realized that the application wasn't working on windows either ! sorry !

Comment: It's ok. If the same client PC loads the applet fine through another app, you may want to check the server-side deployment of the app with problem and see if you miss anything.

Comment: Thanks a ton Rachel ! Will be going ahead with that process in a while .